Find the angle $ECA$
I found this puzzle some time ago on the Internet. Triangle $ABC$ is like on the picture:

where $AD$ is an altitude. One need to find angle $ECA$. How to solve it?
Insane attempt:

$\left|\angle EBD\right|=39^\circ, \left|\angle DEB\right|=51^\circ$
Set $\left|AB\right|=1, \left|\angle ECA\right|=\alpha$
$\left|BD\right|=\sin{33^\circ}, \left|AD\right|=\cos{33^\circ}$
$\left|ED\right|=\sin{33^\circ}\cdot \tan{39^\circ}$
$\left|DC\right|=\cos{33^\circ}\cdot \tan{15^\circ}$
$\tan{\left(75^\circ-\alpha\right)}=\frac{\sin{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ}}{\cos{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{15^\circ}}=\frac{\tan{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ}}{\tan{15^\circ}}$
$\alpha=75^\circ-\tan^{-1}{\left( \frac{\tan{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ}}{\tan{15^\circ}} \right)}$
After proving (I wasn't able to) that $\tan{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ} = \tan{15^\circ}\cdot\tan{63^\circ}$ we are getting $\alpha=12^\circ$

Alternative question would be: How to prove $\tan{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ} = \tan{15^\circ}\cdot\tan{63^\circ}$?

Here is an answer to what you call "the alternative question" :
$$\tan{33^\circ}\cdot\tan{39^\circ} = \tan{15^\circ}\cdot\tan{63^\circ} \  ? \ \ \tag{1}$$
that we write under the form :
$$\frac{\tan{33^\circ}}{\tan{15^\circ}}=\frac{\tan{63^\circ}}{\tan{39^\circ}} \ ? \ \ \tag{1'}$$

Let us first establish that the LHS of (1') can be written under the form :
$$\frac{\tan 33°}{\tan 15°}=\frac{\tan 21°}{\tan 9°}\tag{2}$$
which is equivalent to :
$$\tan 21° \tan 15° = \tan 33° \tan 9°  \tag{2'}$$
An identity which is given and  proved here
Let us copy the first part of their proof : (2) can be transformed into :
$$\underbrace{\sin 33° \cos 15°}\underbrace{ \sin 9° \cos 21°} =\underbrace{ \sin 15° \cos 33° }\underbrace{\sin 21° \cos 9°}$$
which can be transformed, using classical formulas into :
$$\frac 12 (\sin 48°+\sin 18°) \frac 12 (\sin 30°-\sin 12°)=\frac 12 (\sin 48° -\sin 18°)\frac 12 (\sin 30° +\sin 12°)$$
giving :
$$\sin 18° \sin 30° = \sin 48° \sin 12°$$
$$\sin 18° = 2 \sin 48° \sin 12°$$
$$\cos 72° = \cos 36° - \cos 60°$$
which is true by using exact formulas that can be found there.

Besides, let us establish that the RHS of (1') can be written under the form :
$$\frac{\tan{63^\circ}}{\tan{39^\circ}}=\frac{\tan{21^\circ}}{\tan{9^\circ}}
\tag{3}$$
For this purpose, we apply the following identity (that can be found with proof here) :
$$\tan(3x)=\tan x . \tan (60°-x) . \tan (60°+x)$$
to the case $x=21°$ :
$$\tan 63° = \tan 21° \tan 39° \tan 81°$$
which is equivalent to :
$$\tan 63° \tan 9° = \tan 21° \tan 39°$$
proving (3).
Comparison of (2) and (3) gives (1').

One could also use the fact that the sines of multiples of 3° are known : see this dutch document.

We have $\tan(33)=\frac{BD}{AD}$ and $\tan(15)=\frac{CD}{AD}$, so $\frac{\tan(33)}{\tan(15)}=\frac{BD}{CD}$.
But also, $\tan(51)=\frac{BD}{ED}$ and $\tan(DEC)=\frac{CD}{ED}$, so $\frac{\tan(51)}{\tan(DEC)}=\frac{BD}{CD}$.
Can you get it from here? (If you get angle DEC, you can get DCE and thus ECA.)

Arguably you're restating what OP already wrote.

Arguably so. I relied on performing a calculation in the calculator, which turned out exact. I assume then that OP doesn't trust a calculator for #7 in the post. Ordinarily calculator computations are fine in a geometry class, but otherwise, this is turning out to be an interesting question.

Yes, I confirmed my #7 in wolfram, I'm looking for a mathematical proof. Also I'm wondering if there is a "classical way" to get $\alpha$ (without trigonometry).  For example we can see that all angles are multiple of $3^\circ$. Partitioning $18^\circ$ to two angles: $3^\circ$ and $15^\circ$ I went pretty far, but stuck somewhere.

The question can be put in more general terms. Are there triangles which can be dissected in four subtriangles, connected in point E on the altitude.
The given triangle is just one example. And proving that indeed the product of these tangents is equal on both sides is not trivial. I did a numercial search and found many of these triangles.
Just one example.. Again, proving is not trivial.
